# How can I move a paragraph of 4 cm of the margin?

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a letter, and I want to move the address of the destination at 4 cm from the margin. I tries as follow :

```
Patrick Forence\\ 
Street of birds 3\\
1234-Paris\\

\hspace{4cm}John McLee\\    
\hspace{4cm}Street of flowerq 2\\
\hspace{4cm}1234-Paris
```

but it doesn't work. The package I use are:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt]{report}

%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{boiboites}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE. Especially your document class and basic structure are important.

Comment: @user124577: What do you mean by MWE ?

Comment: A MWE (Minimum working example) is the base we build our answers on (so that they fit your needs). See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Why are you using `report` for a letter? There are `letter` and `scrlttr2` to really write letters.

Comment: @user124577: There is no specific reason, but anyway, in report it should be possible to move a small paragraph of 4 cm... I don't understand why my technic doesn't work, it's so weird...

Comment: Try `\hspace*{4cm}Street of flowerq 2\\ \hspace*{4cm}1234-Paris`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arash Esbati mentioned you need to use `\hspace*{}`. Here is a working example:

[image: letter]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\noindent Patrick Forence\\ 
Street of birds 3\\
1234-Paris\\

\noindent\hspace*{4cm}John McLee\\    
\hspace*{4cm}Street of flowerq 2\\
\hspace*{4cm}1234-Paris

\end{document}
```